What is the role and power of the Woman in Genesis3:15 according to Divine Plan of Salvation?
After the Fall of Adam and Eve, we can see in Genesis3:14, that God immediately cursed the serpent, showing that the serpent had done an action contrary to the Will of God, and since angel have superb intellect, they have no excuse for ignorance that it is not against the Will of God. Satan indwelling a Serpent had "touched" Eve.
We can infer that Satan untame when he enters the garden, "touches" Eve, harming a part of her, that was sacred in the eyes of God, like her pure womb.
Why her pure womb? Because the punishment of Eve in Genesis3:16 is about child-bearing.
After God cursed the serpent, removing some of its powers, as some theologians and biblical scholars saw the Serpent, have arms,legs and wings. All of this capabilities were removed by God, and cursed the Serpent to crawl on its bellies. From Serpent to snake, is the cursed.
https://answersingenesis.org/genesis/garden-of-eden/did-the-serpent-originally-have-legs/
And because of this, we can see a tamed Satan in the Book of Job, asking God first the limits, because another action that contradict the Will of God, will be the end of Satan.
And so, God set the clear limits for Satan to follow.

"The LORD said to the satan, “Very well, all that he has is in your power; only do not lay a hand on him.” So the satan went forth from the presence of the LORD."-Job1:12

Job1:12 is a great relief for all mankind, knowing that Satan cannot do anything, that God won't allow, in every man.
Going back to Genesis3:15.
After cursing the Serpent, God the Father immediately declared a WAR, a perennial enmity between Woman vs. Satan.
If God was the one who declared a war, what is the role and power, God had in mind, when He uttered the word "Woman"?
Is there a Church Father's teachings, theologians and biblical scholars who explain the role and power that God will give to a Woman.
In reference to John2:4, it would seem, that the Woman role, is a powerful Intercessor.
In reference to Canticle6:10, the Woman is a powerful Warrior.
John2:4 and Canticle6:10 showed that the Woman's role and power is, a powerful Warrior and Intercessor.
Is there a Church Father's Teachings, Theologians or Biblical Scholars who had described the role and power of the Woman?
Although, Catholicsm is the preferred answer, if there are credible sources, outside Catholicism, like Jewish biblical scholars interpretation and Christian commentaries, answers will be appreciated.no

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1detrAio2zO6Axc5_bsv_EAP7pZy3X55p/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1THtj1bxdee35WhWp-AgRf_Kz8U-Z_Vq6/view?usp=drive_link
Here's a PDF of my thoughts on this, with more on the role of women. Please take a look.

No articulation. Please delete this post.

The links go to very detailed pdfs that the user clearly put effort into.  Seems logical to link to them instead of posting a 20 page long article in detailed subsections. However, the user could have summarized a little bit and done more to explain that on this site (My answer is this and thus, and if you want more detail look at these PDFS I made about it). Also the PDFs do not specifically relate to the topic, but are more generalized. So without any additional effort I would recommend the answer be removed unless the OP corrects these issues.

I didn’t think of that. I’m sorry. I’ll be more mindful next time.
